# With Eclipse Java: Can I run code/tests from within another JVM?

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, remote-access

I know there is remote debugging but I want to go one step further: I would like to run tests in my eclipse that are run within another JVM - i.e. have access to static fields, resources, instances, etc from that JVM.

More specifically: I have an Apache server running locally on my machine and I would like to execute tests as if they were running natively in that very server.

Currently, I implemented my own JUnit test runner that runs within that server/JVM and creates test report XMLs that are written to a folder that I can inspect. But that's a bit bothersome so I would like to be able to run them directly with a mouseclick from eclipse and have them presented there nicely in the JUnit view.

So my question is:

1. Is there a way to run (not debug) code from eclipse within another JVM?
2. If so - is this also possible with tests, i.e. run and check the test reports with the JUnit view?

Comment: It is a bad idea to run unit tests inside another server: test reproducibility.  It is a really bad idea to run unit tests inside a **production** server.

Comment: Thank you @StephenC but 1) As I said the server is running locally so isn't a production server and 2) I don't want to go into detail why I need it but please assume that I very well thought through this and I really need it in that specific case.

Answer (score 0):

A presume that you are talking about an Apache Tomcat server.  (Running unit tests within an *arbitrary* Apache server doesn't make a lot of sense.)

A Google search didn't yield a lot of leads, but I did come across this:

- [JUnit-Tomcat: No Mocking Just Testing](http://www.cs.put.poznan.pl/dweiss/xml/projects/junit-tomcat/index.xml?lang=en)

Be aware that the source code in the code in the downloadable hasn't been updated since 2006.   Apparently doesn't support JUnit 4.0, and it was developed for Tomcat 5.5.

Another option would be to use an embedded Tomcat server within your unit tests; e.g.

- https://github.com/mjeanroy/junit-servers

---

Note: this is not a recommendation.